# how to add the captured images in a view 3 in a row and select from that and showing it in the previous view

Tags: android, imageview

I'm having an Image-View in an activity and I am capturing image by clicking the Image-View.After Capturing I want to show captured images in an view like grid view 3 in a row dynamically with options to take more photos or select one from these.The selected image is set to the Image-View and if user selects take more photos it should capture the photos again and show it in the view.Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

See the complete reference with code sample in the android documentation [photo basics](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html).

Comment: I am able to capture the photo and save it to my Image View.But in between these process I want to show a view which contains the photos taken with options to take more photos,select this photo.I want to know a good way to implement this.